# Why functional languages?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

I see a lot of talk on here about functional languages and stuff.  Why would you use one over a "traditional" language?  What do they do better?  What are they worse at?  What's the ideal functional programming application?

Comment: John Hughes has written a paper about this: [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf).

Comment: A code illustration of how one transforms from structural to procedural to oop to functional programming https://medium.com/@elye.project/why-code-evolve-from-procedural-to-object-oriented-to-functional-programming-13a88292307e?source=friends_link&sk=84f7fa01c79ef45c0db688d0e8ce3cc6

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Functional languages use a different paradigm than imperative and object-oriented languages. They use side-effect-free functions as a basic building block in the language. This enables lots of things and makes a lot of things more difficult (or in most cases different from what people are used to).

One of the biggest advantages with functional programming is that the order of execution of side-effect-free functions is not important. For example, in [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) this is used to enable concurrency in a very transparent way.

And because functions in functional languages behave very similar to mathematical functions it's easy to translate those into functional languages. In some cases, this can make code more readable.

Traditionally, one of the big disadvantages of functional programming was also the lack of side effects. It's very difficult to write useful software without I/O, but I/O is hard to implement without side effects in functions. So most people never got more out of functional programming than calculating a single output from a single input. In modern mixed-paradigm languages like [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) or [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) this is easier.

Lots of modern languages have elements from functional programming languages. C# 3.0 has a lot functional programming features and you can do functional programming in Python too. I think the reasons for the popularity of functional programming is mostly because of two reasons: Concurrency is getting to be a real problem in normal programming, because we're getting more and more multiprocessor computers; and the languages are getting more accessible.

Comment: You CAN do functional programming in python, but it's really terrible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017621/functional-programming-in-python

Comment: It's *not* hard to write IO code in pure functional languages. They all provide a simple mechanism for writing IO code that works just like it does in imperative languages. All they do is *enforce* that you can't call IO code inside other code whose interface is declared as not performing IO. An analogy would be a dynamic language programmer complaining that a statically typed language like Java made it hard to return whatever type she wanted from a method, because she had to return whatever the type declaration said it would return.

Comment: Haskell is an example of pure functional language, which doesn't have the drawback you said. It actually makes dealing with side effects much easier, because side effects are encapsulated, and enables the programmer to achieve a much more powerful level of abstraction than imperative languages... Really, everybody should give Haskell a try, really grasp it, and realise why it is so powerful.

Answer (score 202):

I don't think that there's any question about the functional approach to programming "catching on", because it's been in use (as a style of programming) for about 40 years. Whenever an OO programmer writes clean code that favors immutable objects, that code is borrowing functional concepts.

However, languages that *enforce* a functional style are getting lots of virtual ink these days, and whether those languages will become dominant in the future is an open question. My own suspicion is that hybrid, multi-paradigm languages such as [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) or [OCaml](http://ocaml.org)
will likely dominate over "purist" functional languages in the same way that pure OO language (Smalltalk, Beta, etc.) have influenced mainstream programming but haven't ended up as the most widely-used notations.

Finally, I can't resist pointing out that your comments re FP are highly parallel to the remarks I heard from procedural programmers not that many years ago:

- The (mythical, IMHO) "average" programmer doesn't understand it.
- It's not widely taught.
- Any program you can write with it can be written another way with current techniques.

Just as graphical user interfaces and "code as a model of the business" were concepts that helped OO become more widely appreciated, I believe that increased use of immutability and simpler (massive) parallelism will help more programmers see the benefits that the functional approach offers. But as much as we've learned in [the past 50 or so years](http://blip.tv/file/1472720) that make up the entire history of digital computer programming, I think we still have much to learn. Twenty years from now, programmers will look back in amazement at the primitive nature of the tools we're currently using, *including* the now-popular OO and FP languages.

Comment: Just look 20 years back. I don't thing programming has evolved much. Well have better tools, maybe a new language or 2 but fundamentally not much will change. This will take more than 20 years. We all once thought we would see flying cars in 2000. :)

Comment: "Twenty years from now..." Isn't that how it always works?  It is a good time to be alive, with so much rapid improvement in pretty much every field.

Comment: From Henry Baker: the Algol/Fortran world complained for ages that they didn't see what possible use function closures would have in
efficient programming of the future. Then the 'OO revolution' happened, and now everyone programs using function closures, but they still refuse to to call them that.

Comment: I didn't realize OCaml was Irish.  :)

Comment: O'Caml is Irish though.

Comment: I don't like this implication that "clean code" is a functional concept.

Comment: @alex strange: "Favor immutability" and "avoid side effects" have been good rules of thumb for quite a while in both object-oriented and imperative programming schools. (So what's not to like? ;-)

Comment: @bibac: 20 years ago we were writing C code, and discussing the merits of Clipper or Turbo Pascal. Object Orientation was the exclusive realm of academics. To propose that little has changed is downright absurd.

Comment: And the tools for programming were nothing like the tools we have now.

Comment: @Daniel: Please provide a list of these people who argued for the "merits" of Clipper. They need to be hunted down and brought to justice.

Comment: Probably the person who wrote this answer doesn't know Haskell well. Saying that you "can" do something is different than saying that you "can well" (you can do anything with any language giving an infinity amount of time). Haskell enables the programmer to do a much more concise, easy to read, and free of bug software than any imperative language available. I can't understand why programmers, who are thinkers by excellence, can be sometimes lazy, in learning new things which can help them...

Comment: I was tempted to say "Probably the person who wrote the previous answer doesn't know the history of programming well." but that would be answering snark with snark. The point was that that the style of functional composition is well established, and languages have been getting better at facilitating/enabling/enforcing it. I would agree that Haskell is further along that path than most other alternatives, but it didn't appear from a vacuum. And someone who starts thinking in a more functional way can benefit prior to, and during, the switch to a better language.

Comment: 20 years.... Blackberry 1999.

Comment: @David, come one, don't be a ..., they meant "compared to dBase III". ;) Those poor souls (if still alive) should be hospitalized instead with PTSD.

Comment: @bibac and then, JavaScript appeared!

Answer (score 126):

The main plus for me is its inherent parallelism, especially as we are now moving away from higher CPU clock frequency and towards more and more cores.

I don't think it will become the next programming paradigm and completely replace OO type methods, but I do think we will get to the point that we need to either write some of our code in a functional language, or our general purpose languages will grow to include more functional constructs.

Comment: We already are seeing this happening.  And it will happen more in the future.  So I agree 100% on this point.

Comment: The tricky thing is that it's the shared nothing / no side-effects aspects of FP that make it so suitable for parallelism. And those are the aspects that don't sit well with OO solutions - making effective hybrids is *extremely* hard. Perhaps FP glue between OO nodes?

Comment: For an effective hybrid have a look at the 2.0 branch of the D programming language.  It's an alpha/work in progress, but it's getting there.

Comment: I found this answer interesting, I don't know any functional language, why are they considered more proper for parallelism?

Comment: Since there's no shared data, functions have no side-effects. All you care about is the return value. (This is quite a hard idea for an OO/procedural programmer to get her head round.) Many functions can therefore be called at once, as long as the output from one isn't used as the input to another.

Comment: Erlang and Elixir are functional languages popularly used for their amazing support for concurrency.

Answer (score 79):

Even if you never work in a functional language professionally, understanding functional programming will make you a better developer. It will give you a new perspective on your code and programming in general.

I say there's no reason to not learn it.

I think the languages that do a good job of mixing functional and imperative style are the most interesting and are the most likely to succeed.

Comment: Good point, but I'd like to see an explanation of "in what way will it make you a better developer"

Comment: Different programming paradigms approach problems from different angles and often require a "different way of thinking" or mindset. And training yourself in multiple different ways of thinking (implying learning which one to use in which situation...) is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 59):

I'm always skeptical about the Next Big Thing.  Lots of times the Next Big Thing is pure accident of history, being there in the right place at the right time no matter whether the technology is good or not.  Examples: [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [Tcl/Tk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), and [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl).  They were all flawed technologies, but all wildly successful because they were perceived either to solve the problems of the day or to be nearly identical to entrenched standards, or both.  Functional programming may indeed be great, but that doesn't mean it will be adopted.

But I *can* tell you why people are *excited* about functional programming: many, many programmers have had a kind of "conversion experience" in which they discover that using a functional language makes them twice as productive (or maybe ten times as productive) while producing code that is more resilient to change and has fewer bugs.  These people think of functional programming as a secret weapon; a good example of this mindset is [Paul Graham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Graham_(programmer))'s [Beating the Averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html).  Oh, and his application?  E-commerce web applications.

Since early 2006 there has also been some buzz about functional programming and parallelism.  Since people like [Simon Peyton Jones](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/simonpj/default.aspx) have been worrying about parallelism off and on since at least 1984, I'm not holding my breath until functional languages solve the multicore problem.  But it does explain some of the additional buzz right about now.

In general, American universities are doing a poor job teaching functional programming.  There's a strong core of support for [teaching intro programming using Scheme](http://htdp.org/), and [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) also enjoys some support there, but there's very little in the way of teaching advanced technique for functional programmer.  I've taught such a course at [Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_University) and will do so again this spring at [Tufts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tufts_University).  [Benjamin Pierce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_C._Pierce) has taught such a course at [UPenn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Pennsylvania).  I don't know if [Paul Hudak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Hudak) has done anything at [Yale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_University).  The European universities are doing a much better job; for example, functional programming is emphasized in important places in Denmark, the Netherlands, Sweden, and the UK.  I have less of a sense of what's happening in Australasia.

Comment: I don't know about the UK universities. You're more than likely to find that many universities over here teach very few programming languages (Java, C, maybe Perl if you're lucky). The problem over here is the difference in quality, as the best (few) universities have the best CS programmes.

Comment: I disagree the examples you gave are flawed, niche perhaps, or suited for certain areas, but general purpose enough to be taken up universally without a massive learning curve. that's probably the biggest reason they're so successful.

Comment: I did Forth and Lisp at uni in the UK (as well as Pascal, C, Modula2 and Cobol) but that was 20 years ago..

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Plenty of stuff has been "general purpose enough to be taken up universally without a massive learning curve" and has not caught on.  Examples: Modula-3 died without even leaving a corpse, and Objective C is on life support.  Both are much easier to learn than C++ or Perl.

Comment: I thought the standard was to initially teach an OO language (C++/Java/C#), and then later on teach a course on the basics of computer languages (i.e. create a compiler, etc) in something like scheme

Comment: @John: "OO first" has been popular but seems to be falling out of favor.  There's enough variety in compiler courses that I dare not generalize---plus, lots of students never take compilers.

Comment: I was taught Java/C++ at uni (in Australia), but a few of my co-workers went to different universities where they did several units in Haskell. It was used both for intro to programming and one of their final year units.

I laughed when i heard what my co-worker said to a Java lecturer after he was introduced to casting for the first time (at this point he only knew Haskell) - "What?! You mean you've got something and you don't _KNOW_ what type it is?!"

Comment: Look at what happened to C# with all those Europeans in the team :)

Comment: Well, at the University of California at Berkeley, the intro course is based on Scheme and starts out concentrating on functional programming. OOP is going to be covered later, but so far it has given me a very good overview of functional languages as well as a good argument for using them. My professor here (Dr Brian Harvey) teaches the material very well and will probably get some people to use functional languages; however, he is retiring, so who knows what will happen next...

Comment: You are skeptical about the Next Big Thing? Functional programming was there at least since 1958 (Lisp). What do you mean by saying that functional programming is the next thing?

Answer (score 32):

I don't see anyone mentioning the elephant in the room here, so I think it's up to me :)

JavaScript (JS) is a functional language. As more and more people do more advanced things with JS, especially leveraging the finer points of [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [Dojo Toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit), and other frameworks, functional programming (FP) will be introduced by the web-developer's back-door.

In conjunction with closures, FP makes JS code really light, yet still readable.

Comment: That is how I really started to dig functional programming.  Nothing is better than Prototype.js's list.Each(function(item){}) or jQuery's whole method of operation.

Comment: Javascript allows one to program in a functional way. It is, however, a cross paradigm language, allowing one to program in a variety of different ways (which I prefer, but that's not relevant)... OO, functional, procedural, etc.

Comment: +1, see http://codex.sigpipe.cz/zeta/

Comment: The jQuery object methods are just operations in the list monad. Taking an object that represents a container (or sequence) as input and returning an object container as output is a fine example of a practical reinvention of fmap.

Answer (score 26):

> Most applications are simple enough to be solved in normal OO ways

1. OO ways have not always been "normal." This decade's standard was last decade's marginalized concept.
2. Functional programming is math. [Paul Graham on Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/icad.html) (replace Lisp by functional programming):

> So the short explanation of why this
> 1950s language is not obsolete is that
> it was not technology but math, and
> math doesn’t get stale. The right
> thing to compare Lisp to is not 1950s
> hardware, but, say, the Quicksort
> algorithm, which was discovered in
> 1960 and is still the fastest
> general-purpose sort.

Answer (score 25):

I bet you didn't know you were functional programming when you used:

- [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) formulas
- [Quartz Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Composer)
- [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
- [Logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29) ([turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics))
- [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)
- [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)
- [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) (or [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash)) and [D3.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js)

Comment: How is Javascript considered functional programming?

Comment: It has first-class functions, higher-order functions, closures, anonymous functions, partial application, currying, and composition.

Comment: Haha. Once wrote a load repayment Excel formula that was wider than the screen with nested functions. I sort of knew then I was functionally programming, but didn't know the term yet.

Comment: Please add C to that list

Comment: @MandeepJanjua: Huh? How come? Or why not any language then?

Comment: @daniel1426, imho: without Monads support at language level, no language cannot be called functional. js has no idea about monads and no syntax sugar for it.

Comment: A typical JavaScript code is full of side effects, how is it even functional programming? Having some functional features doesn't make it functional language.

Comment: JavaScript was covered in [Psvensson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504/why-functional-languages/412764#412764).

Answer (score 18):

> The average corporate programmer, e.g.
> most of the people I work with, will
> not understand it and most work
> environments will not let you program
> in it

That one is just a matter of time though. Your average corporate programmer learns whatever the current Big Thing is. 15 years ago, they didn't understand OOP. 
***If*** functional programming  catches on, your "average corporate programmers" will follow.

> It's not really taught at universities
> (or is it nowadays?)

It varies a lot. At my university, [SML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) is the very first language students are introduced to.

I believe [MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massachusetts_Institute_of_Technology) teaches [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) as a first-year course. These two examples may not be representative, of course, but I believe most universities at the very least offer some optional courses on functional programming, even if they don't make it a mandatory part of the curriculum.

> Most applications are simple enough to
> be solved in normal OO ways

It's not really a matter of "simple enough" though. Would a solution be *simpler* (or more readable, robust, elegant, performant) in functional programming? Many things are "simple enough to be solved in Java", but it still requires a godawful amount of code.

In any case, keep in mind that functional programming proponents have claimed that it was the Next Big Thing for several decades now. Perhaps they're right, but keep in mind that they weren't when they made the same claim 5, 10 or 15 years ago.

One thing that definitely counts in their favor, though, is that recently, C# has taken a sharp turn towards functional programming, to the extent that it's practically turning a generation of programmers into functional programming programmers, *without them even noticing*. That might just pave the way for the functional programming "revolution". Maybe. ;)

Comment: MIT _used_ to teach Scheme in its intro CS course, but it uses Python now.

Comment: "15 years ago, they didn't understand OOP" - The problem is that 15 years ago, they didn't understand FP either.  And they still don't today.

Answer (score 15):

Man cannot understand the perfection and imperfections of his chosen art if he cannot see the value in other arts. Following rules only permits development up to a point in technique and then the student and artist has to learn more and seek further. It makes sense to study other arts as well as those of strategy.

Who has not learned something more about themselves by watching the activities of others? To learn the sword study the guitar. To learn the fist study commerce. To just study the sword will make you narrow-minded and will not permit you to grow outward.

-- Miyamoto Musashi, "A Book of Five Rings"

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 13):

One key feature in a functional language is the concept of first-class functions. The idea is that you can pass functions as parameters to other functions and return them as values.

Functional programming involves writing code that does not change state. The primary reason for doing so is so that successive calls to a function will yield the same result. You can write functional code in any language that supports first-class functions, but there are some languages, like [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell), which do not allow you to change state. In fact, you're not supposed to make any side effects (like printing out text) at all - which sounds like it could be completely useless.

Haskell instead employs a different approach to I/O: [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). These are objects that contain the desired I/O operation to be executed by your interpreter's toplevel. At any other level they are simply objects in the system.

What advantages does functional programming provide? Functional programming allows coding with fewer potentials for bugs because each component is completely isolated. Also, using recursion and first-class functions allows for simple proofs of correctness which typically mirror the structure of the code.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think most realistic people think that functional programming will catch on (becomes the main paradigm like [OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-orientation)). After all, most business problems are not pretty math problems, but hairy imperative rules to move data around and display them in various ways, which means it's not a good fit for pure functional programming paradigm (the learning curve of [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) far exceeds OO.)

On the other hand, functional programming is what makes programming fun. It makes you appreciate the inherent, timeless beauty of succinct expressions of the underlying math of the universe. People say that learning functional programming will make you a better programmer. This is of course highly subjective. I personally don't think that's completely true either.

It makes you a better sentient being.

Comment: I don't think that OO is inherently easier than FP. It really depends on your background (I'm a math guy, guess what I find much easier? :) Damn you OO people and your insane rules.

Comment: Monads aren't hard to understand. Don't buy in to that bullcrap.

Comment: -1 OOP is harder than FP

Comment: -1 We wouldn't write optimizing compilers using OCaml or Haskell if FP was only appropriate for pretty maths problems.

Comment: Re *"appreciate the inherent, timeless beauty of succinct expressions of the underlying math of the universe"*: See also [xkcd 224](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/224:_Lisp)

Answer (score 8):

I must be dense, but I still don't get it.  Are there any actual examples of small application's written in a functional language like [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) where you can look at the source code and see how and why it was better to use such an approach than, say, C#?

Comment: Good remark +1. 
@Mendelt: "more accessible" ? Do you mean the headache is quicker when you watch the code ?

Comment: See this F# library: http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html . I'd love to see sample code in C# with parsers that looked half as elegant and readable as the F# code, even if they are compiled to the same instructions. And try porting FParsec from F# to C# and see how the code bloats.

Answer (score 8):

I'd point out that everything you've said about functional languages, most people were saying about object-oriented languages about 20 years ago.  Back then it was very common to hear about OO:

- The average corporate programmer, e.g., most of the people I work with, will not understand it and most work environments will not let you program in it
- It's not really taught at universities (or is it nowadays?)
- Most applications are simple enough to be solved in normal *imperative* ways

Change has to come from somewhere.  A meaningful and important change will make itself happen regardless of whether people trained in earlier technologies take the opinion that change isn't necessary.  Do you think the change to OO was good despite all the people that were against it at the time?

Comment: * The average corporate programmer, e.g. most of the people I work with, will not understand it and most work environments will not let you program in it
- That's _still_ true of OOP in many places I've worked :) (of course they _say_ they're doing OOP, but they're not)

Answer (score 7):

F# could catch on because Microsoft is pushing it.

Pro:

- F# is going to be part of next version of Visual Studio
- Microsoft is building community for some time now - evangelists, books, consultants that work with high profile customers, significant exposure at MS conferences.
- F# is first class .NET language and it's the first functional language that comes with really big foundation (not that I say that [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29), [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell), [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29), [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29), [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml) do not have lots of libraries, they are just not as complete as .NET is)
- Strong support for parallelism

Contra:

- F# is very hard to start even if you are good with C# and .NET - at least for me :(
- it will probably be hard to find good F# developers

So, I give 50:50 chance to F# to become important. Other functional languages are not going to make it in near future.

Comment: I'd argue that Scala was a pretty deep foundation with the JRE.

Comment: Regarding libraries, it really depends what you're doing. F# is targeted at the finance sector and is also applicable to scientific computing but OCaml actually has far better libraries for such applications than .NET. For example, when I came to F# from OCaml I failed to find a decent FFT and ended up writing (and selling) my own in C# and then F#.

Comment: LINQ is a good bridge to using functional concepts with C# and VB.Net... And I find it to be much less painful to read when compared to F#

Answer (score 5):

I think one reason is that **some people feel that the most important part of whether a language will be accepted is how good the language is**.  Unfortunately, things are rarely so simple.  For example, I would argue that the biggest factor behind Python's acceptance isn't the language itself (although that *is* pretty important).  The biggest reason why Python is so popular is its huge standard library and the even bigger community of third-party libraries.

Languages like [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) or [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) may be the exception to the rule on this considering that they're built upon the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)/[CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).  As a result, I don't have an answer for them.

Comment: +1 but don't forget the power of marketing, and the fact that your company's mountain of legacy code isn't going to switch languages by virtue of some cool new trend.

Comment: And you forgot to mention: Google is popularizing python.

Answer (score 4):

Most applications can be solved in [insert your favorite language, paradigm, etc. here].

Although, this is true, different tools can be used to solve different problems. Functional just allows another high (higher?) level abstraction that allows to do our jobs more effectively when used correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that those people who never learned [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) or [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) as an undergraduate are now discovering it.  As with a lot of things in this field, there is a tendency to hype and create high expectations...

It will pass.

Functional programming is great.  However, it will not take over the world. [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), etc. will still be around.

What will come of this I think is more cross-language ability—for example, implementing things in a functional language and then giving access to that stuff in other languages.

Comment: C# is now a functional programming language (as much as Lisp) because it has first-class lexical closures. Indeed, they are already used in WPF and the TPL. So functional programming is obviously already here.

Answer (score 4):

When reading "The Next Mainstream Programming Language: A Game Developer’s Perspective" by Tim Sweeney, Epic Games, my first thought was - I got to learn Haskell.

[PPT](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dpw/popl/06/Tim-POPL.ppt)

[Google's HTML Version](http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:vEhsoTFOx4sJ:www.cs.princeton.edu/~dpw/popl/06/Tim-POPL.ppt+gears+of+war+developer+future+language&hl=lv&ct=clnk&cd=1)

Answer (score 3):

Check out *[Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf)*.

Comment: The link doesn't open. Error 403.

Comment: This might be a good replacement? http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf

Comment: Dead link. This is why these kinds of answers are unfavorable to quoting as well as linking.

Comment: I have fixed the link. @Sylwester that is true, but its a 23 page document. Distilling the paper down to answer on this site would not do it justice.

Answer (score 3):

Things have been moving in a functional direction for a while. The two cool new kids of the past few years, [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) and [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), are both radically closer to functional languages than what came before them—so much so that some Lispers have started supporting one or the other as "close enough."

And with the massively parallel hardware putting evolutionary pressure on everyone—and functional languages in the best place to deal with the changes—it's not as far a leap as it once was to think that [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) or [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) will be the next big thing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you been following the evolution of programming languages lately? Every new release of all mainstream programming languages seems to borrow more and more features from functional programming.

- Closures, anonymous functions, passing and returning functions as values used to be exotic features known only to Lisp and [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) hackers. But gradually, C#, [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi), Python, [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), JavaScript, have added support for closures. It's not possible for any up-and-coming language to be taken seriously without [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).
- Several languages, notably Python, C#, and Ruby have native support for list comprehensions and list generators.
- pioneered generic programming in 1973, but support for generics ("parametric polymorphism") has only become an industry standard in the last 5 years or so. If I remember correctly, [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) supported generics in 2003, followed by Java 2004, C# in 2005, [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi) in 2008. (I know C++ has supported templates since 1979, but 90% of discussions on C++'s [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) start with "here there be demons".)

What makes these features appealing to programmers? It should be plainly obvious: **it helps programmers write shorter code**. All languages in the future are going to support—at a minimum—closures if they want to stay competitive. In this respect, functional programming is already in the mainstream.

> Most applications are simple enough to
> be solved in normal OO ways

Who says can't use functional programming for simple things too? Not every functional program needs to be a compiler, theorem prover, or massively parallel telecommunications switch. I regularly use F# for ad hoc throwaway scripts in addition to my more complicated projects.

Answer (score 3):

It's catching on because it's the best tool around for controlling complexity. 
See:
  - slides 109-116 of Simon Peyton-Jones talk "A Taste of Haskell"
  - "The Next Mainstream Programming Language: A Game Developer's Perspective" by Tim Sweeney

Comment: Links to add:

https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/haskell-tutorial/TasteOfHaskell.pdf

http://www.st.cs.uni-sb.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/sweeny.pdf

Comment: @sastanin: The first link is (effectively) broken; it redirects to a generic page.

Comment: Thanks for finding and checking those links. There's a youTube video of SPJ presenting this slidedeck, which has a link which is still good:  https://www.slideshare.net/oscon2007/os-peytonjones

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the first point, but times change.  Corporations will respond, even if they're late adopters, if they see that there's an advantage to be had.  Life is dynamic.

They were teaching [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) and [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) at [Stanford](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20Stanford) in the late 1990s.  I'm sure that places like [Carnegie Mellon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnegie_Mellon_University), [MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massachusetts_Institute_of_Technology), Stanford, and other good schools are presenting it to students.

I agree that most "expose relational databases on the web" applications will continue in that vein for a long time.  Java EE, .NET, [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), and PHP have evolved some pretty good solutions to that problem.

You've hit on something important: It might be the problem that can't be solved easily by other means that will boost functional programming.  What would that be?

Will massive multicore hardware and cloud computing push them along?

Answer (score 2):

Because functional programming has significant benefits in terms of productivity, reliability and maintainability. [Manycore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manycore_processor#Suitable_programming_models) may be a killer application that finally gets big corporations to switch over, despite large volumes of legacy code. Furthermore, even big commercial languages, like C#, are taking on a distinct functional flavour as a result of manycore concerns. Side effects simply don't fit well with concurrency and parallelism.

I do not agree that "normal" programmers won't understand it. They will, just like they eventually understood OOP (which is just as mysterious and weird, if not more so).

Also, most universities do teach functional programming, and many even teach it as the first programming course.

Comment: Sorry, but FP has been around almost 3 times as long as OOP.  This simply isn't a matter of needing more time.  It will take something more to make FP mainstream.

Comment: How could you miss the part of my post where I explain that the "something more" could very well be many-core?
And something "being around" isn't really relevant. People understood OOP because it offered tangible benefits at the time, FP has only recently become practical.

Answer (score 2):

Wow - this is an interesting discussion. My own thoughts on this:

FP makes some tasks relatively simple (compared to none-FP languages).
None-FP languages are already starting to take ideas from FP, so I suspect that this trend will continue and we will see more of a merge which should help people make the leap to FP easier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it will catch on or not, but from my investigations, a functional language is almost certainly worth learning, and will make you a better programmer. Just understanding referential transparency makes a lot of design decisions so much easier—and the resulting programs much easier to reason about. Basically, if you run into a problem, then it tends to only be a problem with the output of a single function, rather than a problem with an inconsistent state, which could have been caused by any of the hundreds of classes/methods/functions in an imperative language with side effects.

The stateless nature of functional programming (FP) maps more naturally to the stateless nature of the web, and thus functional languages lend themselves more easily to more elegant, [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) web applications. Contrast with [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) frameworks that need to resort to horribly ugly *hacks* like VIEWSTATE and SESSION keys to maintain application state, and maintain the (occasionally quite leaky) abstraction of a stateful imperative language, on an essentially stateless functional platform like the web.

And also, the more stateless your application, the more easily it can lend itself to parallel processing. Terribly important for the web, if your website happens to get popular. It's not always straightforward to just add more hardware to a site to get better performance.

Answer (score 2):

My view is that it will catch on now that Microsoft have pushed it much further into the mainstream. For me it's attractive because of what it can do for us, because it's a new challenge and because of the job opportunities it resents for the future.

Once mastered it will be another tool to further help make us more productive as programmers.

Answer (score 2):

A point missed in the discussion is that the best type systems are found in contemporary functional programming languages. What's more, compilers can infer all (or at least most) types automatically.

It is interesting that one spends half the time writing type names when programming Java, yet Java is by far not type safe. While you may never write types in a [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) program (except as a kind of compiler checked documentation) and the code is 100% type safe.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, casting the solution in pure functional terms forces one to understand the problem better. Conversely, thinking in a functional style will develop better* problem solving skills.

*Either because the functional paradigm is better or because it will afford an additional angle of attack.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not really taught at universities (or is it nowadays?)

I don't know about nowadays, but I was taught both [Miranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_(programming_language)) and Lisp as part of my computer science course in the mid 1990s. Despite not using a pure functional language since, it has influenced the way I solve problems.

> Most applications are simple enough to be solved in normal OO ways

In the same mid 1990s computer science course, OO (taught using [Eiffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language))) was taught pretty much on a par with functional programming. Both were non-mainstream at the time. OO may be "normal" now, but it was not ever thus.

I'll be interested to see whether F# is the thing that pushes functional programming into the mainstream.

Comment: gosh yes, i forgot Miranda - did that too...

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest argument for functional programming languages to become the "next big thing" is that in the future multi-core processors will be the norm.  Programmers will have to take advantage of that, and functional programming offers really wonderful possibilities for building top of the line concurrent software.

P.S. When I was in college at Boston University (1998-2002) we spent a semester learning [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) which is a close cousin of [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29).  When we first started learning it, I wanted to rip my hair out.  By the end of the course it was very natural.

Comment: I had the same experience at Michigan Tech (2003-2008). About halfway through the semester it "clicked". Unfortunately I haven't had a chance to use Scheme for anything since then (I took that class in 2004, I think).

Answer (score 1):

Uh, sorry to be a pedant, but it has already caught on—we call it Excel.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/excel/

The vast majority of programmes that run on computers are written in Excel or one of the many popular clones of it.

(There are many programmes that are run many times, and programmes written in Excel tend *not* to be one of these—most Excel programmes have one run instance.)

Comment: Today, the term "functional programming" means supporting first-class lexical closures and, preferably, tail calls. Excel supports neither.

Comment: The link is broken: *"We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."*

Answer (score 1):

- How long did it take OOP to get understood by the average corporate programmer...?
- I was taught functional programming at Utrecht University in - I think - 1994 and only see it start to catch on "in the real world" in the last couple of years.
- There is no such thing as a "simple application". ;-)

I think that (approaching) side effect-free programming for some key parts of software will be essential when we start to get more and more cores in our hardware. Give functional programming a bit more time. And the functional sprinkling in current and future versions of C# will go a long way in preparing those corporate programmers for functional programming without them even realising it...

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- The debate between functional programming (FP) and imperative programming (OO, structured, etc.), has been raging since [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) versus [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran).  I think you pose excellent questions but recognize that they are not especially new.
- Part of the hoopla over FP is that we seem to be recognizing that concurrency is very difficult, and that locks and other mechanisms in OO (e.g., Java) are just one solution. FP offers a refreshing sea change with ideas such as Actors and the power of stateless computing. To those wrestling with OO, the landscape seems highly appealing.
- Yes, schools teach FP. In fact, the University of Waterloo and others offer [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) in first year classes ([reference here](http://compsci.ca/blog/computer-science-at-waterloo-the-new-scheme-of-things/)).
- Regarding the average programmer, I'm sure that the same arguments were given against C++ back in the early 1990s. And look what happened.  *If* businesses can gain an advantage via a technology, you can bet that people will receive training.

This is not to say that it is a sure thing, or that there won't be a backlash in 3-5 years (as there always is). However, the trend towards FP has merit and is worth watching.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great article from [Slava Akhmechet](http://www.defmacro.org/) called [Functional Programming For The Rest of Us](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/fp.html) (this was the article that got me into functional programming, btw). Amongst the benefits functional programming brings, he unorthodoxly emphasizes the following (which I believe contributes to the appeal for software engineers):

- [Unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)
- Debugging
- Concurrency
- [Hot code deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)#Hot_code_loading_and_modules)
- Machine assisted proofs and optimizations

And then goes on to discuss the goodness of more traditionally discussed aspects of functional programming, like [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), lazy evaluation, optimization, abstracting control structures (although not discussing [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))), infinite data structures, strictness, continuations, pattern matching, [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) and so on.

It is highly recommended!

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time envisioning a purely functional language being the common language of the day, the reasons for which I won't get in to (because they're flame fodder). That being said, programming in a functional way can provide benefits no matter the language (if it allows such). For me, it's the ability to test my code much easier. I work with databases a lot... I tend to:

1. write a function that takes data, manipulates it, and returns data
2. write a dead simple wrapper that calls the database and then returns the result of passing that data through my function

Doing so allows me to write unit tests for my manipulation function, without the need to create mocks and the like.

I do think purely functional languages are very interesting... I just think it's what we can learn from them that matters to me, not what we can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually learning [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) after reading *[Hackers and Painters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackers_%26_Painters)* and I do believe I will *learn* something from Lisp that will give me a better understanding of everything else I program. Now I don’t think I will actually be using Lisp in my everyday just because some guy in 1995 created a website that became Yahoo Stores. So it’s a win-win anyway (if it catches on, I win. If not, I get more points of views on how to program and how stuff works).

Now... on another question kind of related, do I think programming will change a lot with 32 cores processors arriving next year? *Yes*, I don’t know if it will be functional programming, but... I’m pretty sure there will be something different!

Comment: Could you please use capital I 's? it's driving me insane...

Answer (score 0):

It has already caught on with [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) in [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question lies more in the statement, "the right tool for the job", than the hottest thing.  There will always be hot new technologies, and there will always be those who jump on them.

Functional languages have been around for a while; it's just now they are getting more press.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming (FP) is the next best paradigm that is for sure. Now which language could be the next step? That is the hard stuff, but I believe could be [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell), [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure), [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml) or [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29). Or it could be Python with more FP constructs and better support for parallelism/performance or also Perl 6 with [Parrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine) looks very interesting.

Comment: Dem's be fightin' words.

Comment: javascript is already catching on.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people have mentioned functional languages.

But here are some of the *most* commonly used functional languages in use today besides JavaScript:

Excel, SQL, [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), [XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery), [J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_(programming_language)) and [K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)) are used in the financial realm.

And of course [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29).

So I would say that from that list that functional programming techniques are used in mainstream every day.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming will likely be a tool that is used by engineers and scientists to solve the problems that they are facing.  It isn't going to take the world like earlier languages.  However, the hard product to beat is [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel). If I am an engineer and need to do calculations, Excel is awesome.

However, [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) is going to be another source and will likely fill design needs by the non-computer scientists.  Let's face it, computer scientists have done a great job of creating a *whole* new way of doing things.  Object Oriented Programming is *great*.  But sometimes you just need a way to solve an equation, get a solution and graph it.  That's it.  Then a language like F# fills the bill.  Or maybe you want to build a finite state machine, and F# again could be one of the solutions, but then C could be a solution as well.

But when it comes to parallel processing, Excel shines and in time F# will be there as well.  In a friendly manner though, F#= friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is really pushing [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) with the next version on [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). It is a hybrid language such as [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) and integrates very nicely with the rest of the .NET framework. I think a lot of Microsoft shops are going to use it to speed-up the development of highly parallel data-processing applications and functions.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think for distributed systems and multi-threaded/parallel programming functional programming will have a break-through soon. As long as it integrates with existing OOP paradigms through programming libraries. So... the purely functional approach - in my opinion - will remain academic.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming has been around for a long time, since LISP was one of the earliest languages to have a compiler, and since MIT's LISP machines. It's not a new paradigm (OO is much newer) but the dominant software platforms have tended to be written in languages that translate easily to assembly language, and their APIs heavily favor imperative code (UNIX with C, Windows with C, and Macintosh with Pascal and later C).

I think the new innovation in the last few years is for a diversity of APIs to catch on, particularly for things like web development where the platform APIs are irrelevant. Since you're not coding directly to the Win32 API or the POSIX API, that gives people the freedom to try out functional languages.

Comment: Agreed.  The age of the rich API is starting, and it is a powerful concept when done right.  But OOP is not quite the right language technology to support it.  LINQ is good example of things to come - a functional programming foundation, and requiring FP extensions to C# to work.

Answer (score -8):

I don't think that functional languages will solve anything, and that this is just a hype that management is trying to sell. Remember the only truth:

There is [no silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

All the rest is bovine fecal matter. Also they've said that OO would solve our problems, that Web Services would solve our problems, and that XML would solve our problems, but in the end the above truth applied, and everything went down. Also, twenty years from now on, who says that we will be using binary computers at all? Why not quantum computers? No one can predict the future, at least not on this planet. (That is the second truth.)

Comment: Yeah, there's no silver bullet. But is this worth digging out a really old question, which also has a dozen answers saying the same thing? Propably no. Therefore, third only truth: Think, read the question and look at its date before posting.

Comment: @delnan while Coyote21 opinion is unpopular and he doesn't bring much here, **I don't feel like the date of the question is important**. This isn't a forum where old posts shouldn't be touched, it's a collaborative Q&A and anyone at any time can and should contribute with new information.