# F# immutable version of List<T>?

Tags: list, f#, immutability

I'm trying to learn abit of F# for fun at the moment.

In C# I work with complex data from database that must often contain ints, doubles, strings all in one element. The `System.Collections.Generic List<T>` is perfect for this.

I'm trying to explore parallelism in F# but would need an immutable `List<T>` to do so. Is this possible? And would the syntax be similar to C# `var x = new List<T>` ?

Thanks.

I'm going to edit this to make it more clear:

In F# I would like to create an immutable list of classes or records (should be named) just how I would in C# with List. This is so I can work with grouped strings, ints, doubles in the same element. Hopefully this is really simple.

Comment: What do you want to do with F# parallelism? Can you be more specific (by giving an example, etc)?

Comment: F# has a good immutable list type - which you set up like `let mylist = 1::b::c::[]`.  Like pad, I am not sure what the real question is here

Comment: I would suggest you to rephrase your question and provide more details to get more meaningful answers. dont be shy

Comment: And for the downvote, how specific would you like me to be it's already very clear exactly what i want to achieve. How i wish to use an immutable list is entirely irrelevant as all i want to do here is create one.

Comment: This is for parallelising monte carlo simulation therefore the underlying data (array of ints or doubles from an RNG) is immutable once created.

Comment: @RichardTodd i did not down vote, but despite what you added, I still can't understand what you mean by "This is so I can work with grouped strings, ints, doubles in the same element" ....

Comment: Well we could use a list of tuples but most people I know use a list of structs or classes in C# since the items are named and you can have more control through properties. This is all i wanted to do in F# so I can play around with the language in a way that is familiar to me from C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't downvote, but it was difficult to answer your question without more details.

In F#, immutable list is the most frequently used data structure. You often construct lists using cons constructor `(::)` and empty list `[]`. For example, `[1; 2; 3]` is the syntactic sugar for `1::2::3::[]`. You could follow the links suggested by @Brian to read more about basic list processing.

Once you get used to F# list, you could use [high-order functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx) and list comprehension for creating new lists. In your case, a list of random numbers could be generated as follows:

```
let genRand =
    let rand = System.Random()
    fun () -> rand.NextDouble()

/// Creating a list using high-order functions
let genRandList n = List.init n (fun _ -> genRand())

/// Creating a list using list comprehension
let genRandList' n = [ for i in 1..n -> genRand() ]
```

I'm not familiar with Monte Carlo simulation; but reading through [this article](http://it-quant.blogspot.dk/2008/10/monte-carlo-simulation.html), you would apply several `List.map` functions uniformly on list elements once the list of random numbers is generated. For parallelism purpose, I suggest you to employ Array instead of List, which gives much better speedup. Arrays allow random access on elements, so different threads could easily access disjoint parts of an array in parallel. Though arrays are mutable, you could use them in a side-effect free manner thanks to [high-order functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273.aspx) and array comprehension.

In order that a task at each element is significant, you should merge a series of `Array.map` into one and change `Array.map` to [`Array.Parallel.map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821126.aspx) for parallelism. You could also parallelize `mean` function; however, it is unlikely to give you any speedup. Take a look at [this snippet](http://fssnip.net/cr) to see how the solution looks like with arrays.

**UPDATE**:

Create a list of records:

```
type RandPair = { First: float; Second: float}
let genRandPairs n = [ for i in 1..n -> 
                          { First = genRand(); Second = genRand() } ]
```

You could do similarly for [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the good response. I am used to using List<T> in C# like this:

class MyClass {
public int index;
public double number;
}

var myList = new List<MyClass>
myList.Add(new MyClass(1, 0.555));


So I use this for grouping items and this is perfect because I read in data from a database then perform calcs/aggregations on each element and item in the List. So in F# I have just seen only examples of the built-in structs as the datatype, when what I want to do is create a list of records or classes.

Thanks!

Comment: @RichardTodd: See my update above. My advice is that when programming in F#, follow the F#'s way. Otherwise you couldn't get the most out of the language.

Answer (score 3):

Before answering how to use a List, you might want to make sure **why** you would want to use a ***List***.

This is not trivial, because what we refer as a ***List*** in computer science is a very precise structure that has a signification different than, say, a ***sequence***, which corresponds more to casual usage of 'list'. In C# this is called IEnumerable, and is aliased *seq* in F# (they are the same BCL type).

This general functional concept of a sequence can be seen in types like an Array, a List, a Set, a Dictionary, a Map, etc... anything that can be *enumerated*

To give you a feel of what are the different structures, here is a sample list (err.. sequence) of the zoology :

- A **Set** is in itself unordered but can be enumerated even though it is not its first usage
- A **List** is a structure where each element has a pointer to the next element,
  allowing scan, and o(n) random access. in F# it is immutable, you can only create new ones, and not add elements to it. you can have Linked List for 1 way traversal, and Double Linked list for 2-way traversal.
- An **Array** is a continous block of memory that allows o(1) random access, good if you know beforehand the size of your collection
- A **Dictionary** is like an array, but is index by some key that is not an integer
- A **ResizableArray** is akin to the c# List that you know, in that it you can add elements to it in

Everything about List themselves is here

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists

If you understand your program, you should be able to justify beforehand why you use this structure over this other one.

If your program is too slow one day, go look for 'find' on structure where they are o(n).
That is, the equivalent of 'full scan' in databases. Getting the correct structure will then make your program fly

Answer (score 1):

You might check out

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline, as by [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think that, in the context of this question it should be stated that F# immutable structures won't be of great help to you, because if you create immutable F# list as described in other answers, you will only be sure that your list is not modified, whereas references it holds are probably pointing to the objects that are not immutable.

That said, even if they were, the parallelization is not coming automatically. F# is not pure language, so it cannot be sure what kind of side-effects are introduced by your objects, and can't parallelize anything by itself (even if it could, it would probably not be very efficient solution, as automatic parallelization is not that easy).

It's nicely described in following question: [Does F# provide you automatic parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682710/does-f-provide-you-automatic-parallelism)

Of course that's everything general, as we don't know the details of your problem.