# Why no functional programming languages became mainstream

Tags: oop, haskell, programming-languages, functional-programming, erlang

Given so much praise for languages such as haskell, erlang, why none of them can become a mainstream language?

Is it due to their learning curve? Or too much symbol notation?

Comment: "too much symbol notation"? You haven't seen anything yet.

Comment: "learning curve"? "symbol notation"? I think C++ won both of those contests a long time ago. I think comfort and superstition are the main reasons, but Microsoft are making huge efforts in mainstreaming FP. I think VB is the true trojan horse, actually.

Comment: Funny thing is, while few "functional programming languages" have yet become "mainstream", many "mainstream" languages have acquired and are actively acquiring more and more "functional programming" features.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because most people don't know how to program functionally.

Because overcoming a dominant paradigm is difficult and takes time.

Because "nobody ever got fired for choosing Java" (corollary of above, from [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt)).

Because real-world programming isn't always perfectly functional–we love our side-effects.

Etc.

Much more info in [this older SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835936/438992), and unlike mine, it includes machine guns and aliens.